Will using QLayout setParent and setSpacing cause exception?
The following test code will cause a shutdown exception：
QWidget* ppWidget =ui->centralwidget;

QPushButton* pBtn = new QPushButton(tr("ok"), ppWidget);

QLabel* plabel = new QLabel(tr("ok"), ppWidget); QWidget* pwidget = new QWidget(ppWidget); QHBoxLayout* mHLayout = new QHBoxLayout(nullptr); mHLayout->setParent(pwidget); mHLayout->setSpacing(2); pwidget->setLayout(mHLayout);

Through debugging, I found that executing update in setSpacing will cause focus_prev to be modified. I can’t believe why this is happening. In my opinion, this way of writing is very common.
Use
 QHBoxLayout* mHLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pwidget); 

mHLayout->setSpacing(2); 

is normal, no error.
